# Changing Members Edit Permission Level

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I have a Sharepoint List where members can populate with information.

But some members are creating new columns, which has caused confusion for other users.

Is possible to block the "+ Add Column" from Members?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the "Members" group by default is granted the "Edit" permission level, and "Edit" is not what you think it is.

The "**Edit**" permission level specifically grants users the rights to "**Add, edit, and delete lists**; view, add, update, and delete list items and documents. By default, this permission level is assigned to the Members group."

What you want to assign to these users is actually the "**Contribute**" permission level which grants users the rights to "**View, add, update, and delete list items and documents**."

Unlike the "Edit" permission level, SharePoint Online does not assign the "Contribute" permission level to any group by default.  You will either need to [change the Members group's permission level](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/customize-sharepoint-site-permissions#assign-a-new-permission-level-to-a-group) to "Contribute", or create a [new group](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/customize-sharepoint-site-permissions#create-a-group) with that permission level.

For more details on built-in permission levels, [see here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/understanding-permission-levels#default-permission-levels).

Comment: Can't edit the Team Members Permission, so I create a new group and select the *Contribute*. But how can I overlap the default site permission with the newly created permission?

Comment: You'll need to remove the users who you don't want to change stuff, out of the Members group, then add them to your new Contribute group.

Answer (score 1):

Users who are granted with Contribute, Read or lower permissions will not be able to “Add column”.

The button will still be visible to the users, but they can only show or hide columns. If they try to save the modified view as a public view, they will get “Access Denied” error.

You can check user permissions via `https://{siteURL}/_layouts/15/user.aspx` and remove the user from the additional groups.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "Edit", you can assign the "Submit" permission level, which excludes the "Manage Lists" permission. With this permission level people cannot change the structure of a list or the public views.

Or create a new, custom permission level and select the permissions you want to include.

[image]